# TypeScript connect React-Redux decorator with stateful component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have create an illustrative component `Hello` where I attempt to use proper types for `props` and `state` while using the `connect` decorator from React-Redux.

You can play along in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/TomasHubelbauer/react-redux-typescript-connect-decorator-demo/commit/b8aa27708fcb12fa4784e78bf5a1957eeb2e722a) I created to illustrate this.

When `connect` is *not* used as a decorator but instead, `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Hello)` is used and the component itself is not exported, this works.

```
type HelloStateProps = { enthusiasmLevel: number; };
type HelloDispatchProps = { incrementEnthusiasm: () => void; decrementEnthusiasm: () => void; };
type HelloOwnProps = { name: string; };
type HelloProps = HelloStateProps & HelloDispatchProps & HelloOwnProps;
type HelloState = { useHi: boolean; };

// I am getting an error here
@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
export default class Hello extends React.Component<HelloProps, HelloState> {
  state: HelloState = { useHi: false };

  onChangeGreetingButtonClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = event =>
    this.setState(state => ({ useHi: !state.useHi }))

  render() {
    const { useHi } = this.state;
    const { name, enthusiasmLevel } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="hello">
        {useHi ? 'Hi' : 'Hello'} {name} x{enthusiasmLevel}
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.props.decrementEnthusiasm}>-</button>
          <button onClick={this.props.incrementEnthusiasm}>+</button>
          <button onClick={this.onChangeGreetingButtonClick}>Change greeting</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export function mapStateToProps({ enthusiasmLevel }: StoreState): HelloStateProps {
  return { enthusiasmLevel };
}

export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<EnthusiasmAction>): HelloDispatchProps {
  return Redux.bindActionCreators({ incrementEnthusiasm, decrementEnthusiasm }, dispatch);
}
```

The error I am getting when attempting to use `connect` as a decorator is as follows:

```
Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<HelloProps, "name">> & { WrappedComponent: ComponentType<HelloProps>; }' is not assignable to type 'typeof Hello'.
    Type 'Component<Pick<HelloProps, "name">, ComponentState>' is not assignable to type 'Hello'.
      Types of property 'state' are incompatible.
        Type 'Readonly<ComponentState>' is not assignable to type 'HelloState'.
          Property 'useHi' is missing in type 'Readonly<ComponentState>'.
```

When I strip the component of state fully, like this:

```
@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
export default class Hello extends React.Component<HelloProps> {
  render() {
    const { name, enthusiasmLevel } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="hello">
        Hi {name} x{enthusiasmLevel}
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.props.decrementEnthusiasm}>-</button>
          <button onClick={this.props.incrementEnthusiasm}>+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

…I get this error instead:

```
Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<HelloProps, "name">> & { WrappedComponent: ComponentType<HelloProps>; }' is not assignable to type 'typeof Hello'.
    Type 'Component<Pick<HelloProps, "name">, ComponentState>' is not assignable to type 'Hello'.
      Types of property 'render' are incompatible.
        Type '() => string | number | false | Element | Element[] | ReactPortal | null' is not assignable to type '() => Element'.
          Type 'string | number | false | Element | Element[] | ReactPortal | null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
            Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
```

Where is the problem? I don't understand the error messages.

In the stateful one, `state` should make 0 difference to `connect`, right? So why is it even reported? And `useHi` is most certainly not missing in `ReadOnly<HelloState>`, but where is `ComponentState` coming from?

In the stateless one, `render`, when hovered over, shows `JSX.Element` return type. So what is up with that `null`?

Comment: Please provide version of Typescript you using

Comment: Seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/9951).
Couple of workaround listed above like `@(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) as any)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/9951).

Couple of workaround listed above like :

```
@(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) as any)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'd advise people stick with `export default connect` and not use that workaround as that will trash your component's `props` types in JSX.